# Bluetooth connection issue in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, a2dp

When I try connecting to the bluetooth device I get the following log via `journalctl -f` command in my terminal.

[image]

I do not know if it is the issue with the driver or installation process.

Comment: Please provide additional details, such as version numbers of the software.

Comment: Thanks, @RohitGupta for the response. I was finally able to solve the issue. The issue was with PulseAudio. I have replaced it with Pipewire and it worked like a charm.